# display images dynamically in repeater tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have multiple images which i want to display. the image count varies on input. I am able to see the broken images on the screen. In console the ERR_INVALID_URL is displayed. Please let me know where i am wrong.

Below is my **aspx code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server"     
             ImageUrl="data:image/jpg;base64,<%# ((view_data)Container.DataItem).image%>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**cs code**

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
     Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])row["image"];
     viewDataList.Add(new view_data { image = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)});
 }
 Repeater1.DataSource = viewDataList;
 Repeater1.DataBind();
```

I am fetching the images from database.Is this the correct way to do this.. Kindly suggest

Update..

I have changed the image tag to the below. Now there are 4 images that need to be displayed out of which i am able to see 1 image and the rest 3 are broken.. Kindly suggest

```
           <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%# ((view_data)Container.DataItem).image%>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the image tag to the below worked for me..

```
 <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%# ((view_data)Container.DataItem).image%>" />
```

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way with your requirements. Let me know, if you have any issues once you completed with below methods.

**Note:** I tried with separate column name as Image ID.If you have it in your database it will be of more useful to proceed this. Otherwise, you pass the Image directly to the repeater and pass the same to the ImageHandler.ashx

**HTML Page:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("ImageID") %>' Height="150px" Width="150px"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**CS Code:**

On your click event:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT imagename,ImageID from [Image]",connection);
SqlDataAdapter daimages = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
daimages.Fill(dt);
Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

ImageHandler.ashx

After Completion of above code we need to add HTTPHandler file to our project to retrieve images from database because we save our images in binary format getting the binary format of data from database it’s easy but displaying is very difficult that’s why we will use HTTPHandler to solve this problem.

Here HTTPHandler is a simple class that allows you to process a request and return a response to the browser. Simply we can say that a Handler is responsible for fulfilling requests from the browser. It can handle only one request at a time, which in turn gives high performance.

Right Click on your project add new HTTPHandler.ashx file and give name as ImageHandler.ashx and write the following code in pagerequest method like this

```
string strcon =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["ImID"];
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Image from Image where ImageID="+ imageid, connection);
SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
connection.Close();
context.Response.End();
}
```

Here don’t forgot to set the connection string in web.config file here I am getting database connection from web.config file for that reason you need to set the connectionstring in web.config file like this

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="dbconnection" connectionString="DataSource=Yourservername;Integrated Security=true;InitialCatalog=Your databasename"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Source: [Retrieve Image from database](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-to-insert-images-into-database-and.html)

Comment: I want to display multiple images on the screen. Using the above i think i can display only 1 image at a time..

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to foreach to bind data in repeater you can directly specify DataTable to Your repeater control

```
     DataTable dt=new DataTable();
     dt=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
     Repeater1.DataBind();
```

you can place this line

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server"     
         ImageUrl='<%#Bind("image")%>' />
```

instead of

```
<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server"     
         ImageUrl="data:image/jpg;base64,<%# ((view_data)Container.DataItem).image%>" />
```